# Compile Matlab code for Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino

I understand there is a way to compile and upload MATLAB Simulink code to an Arduino so you don't have to have the Arduino connected to your computer.  Is there a way to compile and upload a MATLAB script file of code that I have written myself to the Arduino so it can work independently from being plugged in. i.e. could I upload something like:

```
a = arduino('COM3')
a.pinMode(13,'output');

i = 0
while i>0
a.digitalWrite(13,1)
pause(1)
a.digitalWrite(13,0)
pause(1)
end
```

how would I do this and does it still require code lines like:
    a = arduino
and putting the a. in front of the lines of code